# How to quit a hardcore porn addiction?

Tags: lust

Basically I trained my brain to be dependend on porn over the last 10 years(im 21).
Is like a crack addiction but I have infinite crack at 3 seconds away from me,on my phone and laptop.
I tried to install filters but it takes a few minutes to disable them,even these of them with password.
Please help me, it ruins my mental integrity, it makes me feel dirty and filthy. It makes my mind weaker and it causes a lot of brainfog.Also I become obsessed with porn stars and porn scenes.
I am not a budhist,neither a religious one per se,but I know that God exists.
Also I've been meditating a lot in the last months,but I still fail to abstain,and after one relapse there comes 100 more because of the coolidge effect.

I am very open minded to anything.
Thank you in advanve, much peace and love.

Comment: Find better food.

Comment: @Andreivolkov example of better food that similar level of dopamine?

Comment: @littlestar for example Sports, Performing Arts.